# Combining linesegments that are contionous into one feature in QGIS 3.10.7

Tags: qgis, line, merge, linestring

I have a dissolved line, where I have clipped some segments where I would like to create a feature for each individual segment.

I have tried using `"Vector Geometry -> Multipart to singlepart"`, but the linesegments gets divided into even smaller parts, as shown in the figure below.

Is there a way to combine the linesegments into individual features?

[image: Uncombined linesegments]

Comment: Do you have some attribute to distinguish the red line from the connected blue line? Then dissolve again using that attribute as dissolve field then multipart to singelpart

Comment: The red line is selected using "Identify Features", since the input is dissolved before "Multipart to singlepart" is used it holds the same attributes as all the other lines. In the image there are 3 line segments that should have their own features. So a long answer short, no it does not.

Comment: The only way that I found that could work is to Buffer->Polygons to lines->polygonize->clip, but that seems like its to many steps for what should be "simple"

Comment: Have you tried [Split vector layer](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_general_tools/splitvectorlayer.html)?

Comment: Seems like I would have to have a segment identifier to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The "merge lines" algorithm can do this -- it joins touching segments from multilinestring features into a single continuous linestring